# Search filter for opencart

Tags: php, search, opencart

I am confused about something and need your help.
There are some nice **Product Filter** extensions for opencart however, non of them is providing any function on front page (landing page).

What i want is something like this Magento theme http://xhtml.webtemplatemasters.com/car-dealer

I mean, the viewer should have the facility to search or filter according to his needs right from the front page of my site i.e. by brand, by type, by price etc.

Can you friends guide me how to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you manage to find out how do you do that? I am also interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the search controller and template and extract the information relating to the search, then instead of processing the information on the same page simply post to the current search page. This should limit your need to delve into the code of the search and focus what you need to change to the controller and view.